# Вывести одноименные узлы из XML документа все вместе

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Необходимо вывести все узлы Zakaz вместе

```
DECLARE @docxml xml;
SET @docxml='<Root>
                <Shop>
                <Items>
                    <Zakaz ZakazID="1" ZakazName="Tablets1" ZakazCategory="A">
                        <Price nom="RUB" pnom="650"/>
                        <Firms lang="русский">
                            <Firma>
                            Фирма1
                            </Firma>
                            <Firma>
                            Фирма2
                            </Firma>
                        </Firms>
                        <Features>
                        <Description>Описание товара Tablets1</Description>
                        </Features>
                    </Zakaz>
                    <Zakaz ZakazID="2" ZakazName="Tablets2" ZakazCategory="B">
                        <Price nom="DOL" pnom="150"/>
                        <Firms lang="английский">
                            <Firma>
                            Firma1
                            </Firma>
                            <Firma>
                            Firma1
                            </Firma>
                        </Firms>
                        <Features>
                        <Description>Описание товара Tablets2</Description>
                        </Features>
                    </Zakaz>
                    <Zakaz ZakazID="3" ZakazName="Tablets3" ZakazCategory="C">
                        <Price nom="RUB" pnom="300"/>
                        <Firms lang="русский">
                            <Firma>
                            Фирма3
                            </Firma>
                            <Firma>
                            Фирма4
                            </Firma>
                        </Firms>
                        <Features>
                        <Description>Описание товара Tablets3</Description>
                        </Features>
                    </Zakaz>
                </Items>
                </Shop>
                <Shop>
                <Items>
                    <Zakaz ZakazID="4" ZakazName="Tablets4" ZakazCategory="A">
                        <Price nom="RUB" pnom="1000"/>
                        <Firms lang="русский">
                            <Firma>
                            Фирма5
                            </Firma>
                        </Firms>
                        <Features>
                        <Description>Описание товара Tablets4</Description>
                        </Features>
                    </Zakaz>
                </Items>
                </Shop>
            </Root>';
SELECT  T.query('./Zakaz'),
        C.query('./Zakaz')
FROM @docxml.nodes ('/Root/Shop[1]/Items') col(T)
CROSS APPLY @docxml.nodes ('/Root/Shop[2]/Items') tab(C)
```

У меня получается только в две ячейки. А как сделать в одну ячейку вывод? Может как-то через concat?

Должен быть вывод всех 4-х узлов Zakaz в одной ячейке как на скрине
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и при открытии полученного документа должны выводиться 4 узла

```
<Zakaz ZakazID="1" .....>
.
.
.
</Zakaz>
<Zakaz ZakazID="2" .....>
.
.
.
</Zakaz>
<Zakaz ZakazID="3" .....>
.
.
.
</Zakaz>
<Zakaz ZakazID="4" .....>
.
.
.
</Zakaz>
```

Сделал по другому, но теперь две строки получается с одним и тем же ответом. Как сделать, чтобы была одна строка?

```
DECLARE @docxml xml;
SET @docxml='<Root>
                <Shop>
                <Items>
                    <Zakaz ZakazID="1" ZakazName="Tablets1" ZakazCategory="A">
                        <Price nom="RUB" pnom="650"/>
                        <Firms lang="русский">
                            <Firma>
                            Фирма1
                            </Firma>
                            <Firma>
                            Фирма2
                            </Firma>
                        </Firms>
                        <Features>
                        <Description>Описание товара Tablets1</Description>
                        </Features>
                    </Zakaz>
                    <Zakaz ZakazID="2" ZakazName="Tablets2" ZakazCategory="B">
                        <Price nom="DOL" pnom="150"/>
                        <Firms lang="английский">
                            <Firma>
                            Firma1
                            </Firma>
                            <Firma>
                            Firma1
                            </Firma>
                        </Firms>
                        <Features>
                        <Description>Описание товара Tablets2</Description>
                        </Features>
                    </Zakaz>
                    <Zakaz ZakazID="3" ZakazName="Tablets3" ZakazCategory="C">
                        <Price nom="RUB" pnom="300"/>
                        <Firms lang="русский">
                            <Firma>
                            Фирма3
                            </Firma>
                            <Firma>
                            Фирма4
                            </Firma>
                        </Firms>
                        <Features>
                        <Description>Описание товара Tablets3</Description>
                        </Features>
                    </Zakaz>
                </Items>
                </Shop>
                <Shop>
                <Items>
                    <Zakaz ZakazID="4" ZakazName="Tablets4" ZakazCategory="A">
                        <Price nom="RUB" pnom="1000"/>
                        <Firms lang="русский">
                            <Firma>
                            Фирма5
                            </Firma>
                        </Firms>
                        <Features>
                        <Description>Описание товара Tablets4</Description>
                        </Features>
                    </Zakaz>
                </Items>
                </Shop>
            </Root>';
SELECT  T.query('//Zakaz')

FROM @docxml.nodes ('/Root/Shop/Items') col(T);
```

Comment: В каком виде нужно получить результат?

Comment: Указал в каком виде должен быть результат

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Додумал сам. Немного nodes переделал и всё:

```
SELECT  T.query('//Zakaz')
FROM @docxml.nodes ('./*') col(T);
```